# What is wrong with my spider? It starts and ends within seconds, creating an empty file

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader

class Summoner(scrapy.Item):
    summ = scrapy.Field()
    rank = scrapy.Field()

class myspider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider1'
    start_urls = ['https://www.op.gg/ranking/ladder/']
    def parse(self, response):
        sel = scrapy.Selector(response)
        summoners = sel.xpath('//ul[@class="ranking-highest__list"]/ul')

        for ran, summon in enumerate(summoners):
            item = ItemLoader(Summoner(), summon)
            item.add_xpath('summ', './/li/a/text()')
            item.add_value('rank', ran)
            yield item.load_item()
```

My intention is getting every summoners name from the leaderboard along with its rank (through `enumerate`).

I then run `scrapy runspider myscript.py -o results.xml` and spider stops out leaving a 0 byte .xml file.

No errors shown.

I have tried changing xpath from `summoners` multiple times without any success.

Also, an additional question: Am I supposed to 'figure' xpath by myself like I attempted above, or I should just copy it from Inspect element? Doing so, I get something like this `/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/ul` (which still doesn't work btw)

I'm sure my problem lays in `xpath`, may you correct me?

Comment: I don't see an entry (starting) point in your script, and `parse` is defined inside `myspider`, but never used.

Comment: Since you appear to be trying to parse a single webpage, perhaps consider using BeautifulSoup instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xpaths were wrong. Try the following instead:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader

class Summoner(scrapy.Item):
    summ = scrapy.Field()
    rank = scrapy.Field()

class myspider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider1'
    start_urls = ['https://www.op.gg/ranking/ladder/']
    
    def parse(self, response):
        for summon in response.xpath('//ul[@class="ranking-highest__list"]/li[contains(@id,"summoner-")]'):
            item = ItemLoader(Summoner(), summon)
            item.add_xpath('summ', './/a[@class="ranking-highest__name"]/text()')
            item.add_xpath('rank', './/*[@class="ranking-highest__rank"]/text()')
            yield item.load_item()
```